How to use Androids System Color in Webpage or PWA
Is there a way to use Androids System Color in Webpages or PWAs?
Since Android 14 (13) there is a system wide color theme in Android? How can I get and use this values in my Web Application or PWA?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

See <system-color> by Mozilla.
Check it's Browser compatibility chapter, AccentColor and AccentColorText  are supported by Firefox, other system colors are supported by Firefox and Chrome.
And this may be helpful for you:
CSS System Colors from Jim Nielsen’s Blog.
